# Viewport / Autozoom for desktop view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I designed a website to be used as digital signage 1920x1080 filling entire screen.

is there such a thing to work (sort of like a viewport works on mobile) to zoom all text/images recursive  to all sub DIV's etc as if you hit Ctrl - to zoom in your browser settings.

i want this to happen on page load or adjusting window size. it should scale to the best possible width height to fit in that desktop window's size height.

looking for an option in either CSS  or as a jquery plugin. i googled around and did not find anything.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using media queries? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media

Comment: i know i can re-code using media queries, i don't want to do that. its already built. i want a plugin or command to run on the body to autosize everything automatically. like on a viewport you can do initial zoom....

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"> is your best bet but it will not reorganise your structure to make best use of the screen estate. Media queries add to your code, they don't rewrite it. You're going to have to make the effort to make it responsive, there's no plugin in the world that will resize everything perfectly for you.

Comment: solved using css transform scale https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - ENJOY
CSS Transform  Scale https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

```
 function scalebody() {
                    var veiwwid = $(window).width() / 1920;
                    var veiwwidhh = $(window).height() / 1080;
                    if(veiwwidhh < veiwwid){veiwwid = veiwwidhh;}
                    $('body').css( {"transform": "scale("+veiwwid+")"});
                    var margintop =     ((1080 - $(window).height() )/2) *-1 ;
                    var marginleft =    ((1920 - $(window).width() )/2) *-1 ;
                    $('body').css( {"margin-top": margintop, "margin-left": marginleft});
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){scalebody();});
            $(window).resize(function() {scalebody();});
```